# How to use web3js to put it in json?

Tags: web3js, javascript, json-rpc, private-key, public-key

I have used web3js by using it in the form of node(npm). But I don't know how to extract some data generated from nodes.

Does anyone know this web3js so the results can be changed to json form? Because I need this so that the data generated can be entered into the variable, so that I can then process the variable into the program.

Like let's say I use the web3-eth-accounts package as follows (use node with cmd) :

```
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts')
var accounts = new Accounts('https://rinkeby.infura.io/')
accounts.create()
```

Example result from node :
[image]

Well, for the above does anyone know to be converted into json form?

Comment: The question is not related to Ethereum or web3js, it is javascript coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts')
var accounts = new Accounts('https://rinkeby.infura.io/')
var account = accounts.create()

console.log(account.address, account.privateKey)
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your info, that means a lot to me.